# Confused with proof exercise real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I'm sure it's easy, but I can't see why. Let $p,q,n\in\mathbb{N}$, if $p/q\in(0,1/n)$, then $1/q\in(0,1/n)$.

> If $p/q\in(1,1+1/n)$, show that $1/q\in(0,1/n)$.

Attempt: Since $q\in\mathbb{N}$, $0<1/q$. Now, if $p/q\in(1,1+1/n)$, then we can write $p/q$ as

$$
p/q = 1 + a/b,
$$

where $a/b\in(0,1/n)$, and $a/b$ is rational. By hypothesis, $1/b\in(0,1/n)$. How does one show that $1/q<1/n$? I thought in using contradiction for $1/n\leq 1/q$ but I can't find where everything breaks down.

Comment: You wrote $p/q\in (0,1/n)$ and $p/q\in(1,1+1/n)$ !?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner it's interesting that *both* imply $\frac 1q < \frac 1n$.  In fact if $\frac pq \in (m, m + \frac 1n)$ then $\frac 1q < \frac 1n$ no matter what $p$ or $m$ are.  The $p$ and $m$ are irrelevant!

Comment: A different way to do this is to note $\frac 1q \in (0, \frac 1n) \iff 0 < \frac 1q < \frac 1n \iff 0 < n < q$.  Then  if $\frac pq \in (m, m + \frac 1n)$ so $m < \frac pq < m + \frac 1n< m + 1$.  so $mnq < p < mnq + mq< mnq + n$ so $0 < mq < n$.  So $0 < q \le mq < n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $1 < \frac{p}{q} < 1 + \frac{1}{n}$, we have $0 < \frac{1}{q} \le \frac{p - q}{q} < \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Might be easier to use inequality notation.  Remember $k \in (a,b)$ means nothing more or less than $a < k < b$.

ANd if we keep in mind that if $p \in \mathbb N$ that means $0 < 1 \le p$.

And if we keep in mind that if $a< b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$.

And that if $q > 0$ then $\frac 1q > 0$  then *everything* falls into place!

....

$\frac pq \in (0, \frac 1n)\implies$

$0 < \frac pq < \frac 1n$.

And $0 < 1 \le p$ means

$0 < 1*\frac 1q \le p*\frac 1q$ so

$0 < \frac 1q \le \frac pq$ and $0 < \frac pq < \frac 1n$ so

$0 < \frac 1q < \frac pq < \frac 1n\implies$

$0 < \frac 1q < \frac 1n\implies$

$\frac 1q \in (0, \frac 1n)$.

That's it!

And

$\frac pq \in (1, 1 + \frac 1n) \implies$

$1 < \frac pq < 1 + \frac 1n \implies$

$0 < \frac pq - 1 < \frac 1n \implies$

$0 < \frac pq - \frac qq < \frac 1n \implies$

$0 < \frac {p-q}q < \frac 1n$.

And $0 < \frac {p-q}q$ means $0*q < \frac {p-q}q*q$ means $0 < p-q$.  But $p-q$ is an integer so $p-q \ge 1$.

So $0 < \frac 1q \le \frac {p-q}q < \frac 1n$ so

$0 < \frac 1q < \frac 1n$ so

$\frac 1q \in (0, \frac 1n)$.

That's it.